# Vertx with Spring boot - right mix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vert.x

Vertx and Spring boot are different - how much do I benefit building applications with Vertx - say a REST service with database persistence - on top of Spring boot? Do we benefit from Spring's transaction management, data caching and other features other than dependency injection? What do you think?

Do the Spring framework's blocking design influence Vertx concurrent nature anyway?

Comment: Springs concurrent solution is called Webflux thats the equivalent of Vertx

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Vert.x is much more than a reactive webserver framework: it's a whole ecosystem of reactive servers and clients

Comment: @vijay-veeraraghavan if you are starting from scratch, there is probably little benefit to mix Vert.x and Spring Boot. If you fear you will be missing dependency injection, there are light alternatives to Spring DI (Guice or Dagger).

Comment: Apologize for not mentioning my experiences with vertx - I have developed few not-so-complex resttful services with vertx, but not with Spring or guice. Do the blocking nature of spring effect vertx anyway? Yes, the vertx is a general purpose framework to develop highly reactive & concurrent application, it can be a simple client server or be web, or can even be a timed event that emits data to eventbus.

Comment: I do know that vertx is a full flora of different libraries. When TS is referreng to "the blocking nature of spring" i dont think he knows what he iscompaaring. Spring has its "non blocking" option  which is called webflux. What is blocking in spring boot is the defacto standard of using JDBC blocking drivers, and tomcat servlet technology (yes i know de facto that latest servlet spec supports non-blocking io). But If you want to compare non-blocking technologies you should compare vertx and webflux using a non blocking dbdriver like R2DBC

Comment: compare any nonblocking application to any blocking application, ofc the nonblocking will have higher performance in many tasks. Its a matter of trading memory for CPU or vice versa